# jQuery Parallax Background Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I have the following jQuery code to animate the background images with a parallax effect.

I have two parallax images on my page and it seems the background position of the second one located further down is already way out of position. I believe it's because the scrollTop function is constantly changing from the top of the site and not to the top of the div that the background image resides.

I got the code from here https://gist.github.com/omgmog/7198844

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

I've added this to a JSFiddle here to help someone figure the issue out -

jsfiddle.net/Ls0ftxvq/

```
    $(function() {
        var $el = $('.parallax-background');
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
            $el.css({
                'background-position':'center '+(-.4*scroll)+'px'
            });
        });
        $(window).scroll();
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet with all your code here? It will be easy to debug.

Comment: Hi there, please see this JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Ls0ftxvq/

Comment: This code gives problem in most of the cases. You need an appropriate background image with extra background size mentioned(more than 100%). I tried with 150% just for testing. But the best approach is to use CSS solution.

Comment: I don't want to use a CSS solution as it doesn't look as elegant as the background scrolling with the page and background-attachment fixed has issues on newer iPhones with regards to zoomed in a blurriness.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use just CSS for do parallax effect?
Remove your javascript and add this code in your css file

```
.full-heignt {
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

you have an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yzL3ardm/) based on your code

Comment: Unfortunately, background-attachment fixed causes blurred, zoomed in issues on newer iPhones. Plus I do prefer the image scrolling smoothly with the page scroll. I thought someone might be able to modify my code to get it to work.